# Insert Into Table using Where Clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-insert

**CONTEXT**

I'm using SQL Server Express to track in and out actions.  I have two tables (table1, table2).  Table1 contains ID and startTime keys while Table2 contains ID, startTime, and endTime.

Whenever an entry is made, a row is populated in Table1 with all the keys.  These keys are then inserted in to Table2.

**PROBLEM**

The problem I'm running in to is that I want it to recognize whether or not the ID already exists in Table2 - and, if it does, update the row for that ID instead of creating a new one.

**CURRENT WORK**

```
IF(COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1    --When ID has been seen more than once?
   INSERT INTO Table2(ID, startTime)
   SELECT ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM Table1
   WHERE ID = Table2.PTID

ELSE
   INSERT INTO Table2(ID, startTime)
   SELECT ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM Table1
```

Thanks in advance for any help!  Sorta new to SQL, let me know if there's anything I can do to improve my question.

Comment: take a look at MERGE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
   Update Table2
   SET Table2.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = Table1.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  --However you want to update
   FROM Table2 tab2
   JOIN Table1 tab1 on Table1.ID = Table2.PTID
ELSE
   INSERT INTO Table2(ID, startTime)
   SELECT ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM Table1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  It seems like the code will work I'm just getting an error at the SET CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  line that is preventing it from running.  It says "Incorrect Syntax Near the Keyword CURRENT TIMESTAMP".

Comment: Made a small edit to line 3 - I wasn't specifying the table.field that we were updating.

Comment: Thanks for your help